# Changing B/W flat image to another color

Tags: color, black, white

I just made a prom-shirt of my class. 
Here's how it looks: [image]

Am I able to change the black color of these into another color, like blue "in a single click"
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @hello and welcome to GD.SE what application do you want to use for the single click? Is imagemagick ok or do you want to use Photoshop? Why a single click?

Comment: Yes there are ways, what software are you using? I'd also mention though that if the goal is making t-shirts you probably don't need to change the color. Just tell your manufacturer what ink/dye to associate with this plate. See this for more information: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36272/how-should-artwork-be-setup-for-t-shirt-printing

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify application here's how you do in Photoshop.

1. Make a color fill layer move it under your image
2. Make your image color mode **Screen**

[image: organisation]

**Image 1**: Described setup

You can now double click on the color fill layer, Photoshop will open a color picker dialog to change the color.

[image: color picker]

**Image 2**: Change color by double clicking on Color Fill 1

You could do same in GIMP, imageMagick you name it.