# Watercolor Art Work Prepared for Screen Printing on Fabric

Tags: gradient, screen-printing

Can watercolor artwork be printed on fabric, noting that the fabric is white? if yes how can it be prepared and if not what options do i have? Thank you

Comment: Hi Mona, welcome to GD.SE, this posible duplicate question has a big explanation about how to prepare an artwork for screen-printing.

Answer (score 0):

If it will be printed using screenprint technique, then you need to do a color separation. The Separations are converted to halftone by the printer. Screenprinting and colorseparations are covered in another post [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36272/how-should-artwork-be-setup-for-t-shirt-printing?rq=1).

There is also a good guide to this on: http://popculturetees.com/2008/09/17/gradients-and-halftones-in-screen-printing/

I hope this is helpful.